# Laravel migration: Specified key was too long; max key length is 767 bytes

Tags: mysql, laravel

I have a migration like this:

```
    Schema::table('table', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->string('description', 500)->index()->change();
    });
```

But I get this error:

```
SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1071 Specified key was too long; max key length is 767 bytes (SQL: alter table `...` add index `tags_description_index`(`description`))
```

What I have tried:

(1) change `->index()` to `index("t_index")`. Same error.
(2) In `AppServiceProvider`:

```
public function boot()
{
    Schema::defaultStringLength(512);
}
```

Same error.

Not sure what to do. I did not get the error on my local environment, just now that I am trying to deploy.

Comment: Try installing a newer mysql version on your server (MySQL <=  5.7.7 or MariaDB <= 10.2.2)

Comment: Alternatively, only index the first x chars of your text. You would need to use something like `DB::statement('ALTER TABLE table
 ADD INDEX description (description(10));')`

Answer (score 1):

You should change type field, because type `string` has max length 256. 
Please, change type on `text` or `longtext`

For example:

```
 Schema::table('table', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->text('description', 500)->index()->change();
    });
```

You should read this article
https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/migrations#creating-columns